# Selenium WebDriver. Как перейти на первую ссылку с поиска?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: s]
Надо перейти на первую ссылку с результата поиска, как правильно ее задать? Пытаюсь найти этот элемент через By.xpath(). Но не понимаю, что вписывать в скобки. Помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходим такой xpath :

`./div[@class='search-result']/div[@class='search-item][1]/h4/a'`

Answer (score 0):

В хроме можно копировать full XPath для таких случаев мне больше он нравится.
Но обычный XPath тоже подойдет, его также можно скопировать в элементах разработчика.
Если по какой-то причине нужно самому писать, то почитай по [ссылке](https://www.guru99.com/xpath).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]